# Lost/confused in optimizing

Tags: c, optimization, for-loop, openmp, raytracing

I just completed a computer graphics course, where we had to program a ray tracer. Though all the results were correct, I was confused about the use of OpenMP (which BTW was not part of the course). I have this loop (C++):

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(L, ray)
//  for (x = x_from; x < x_till; x++) {
//  printf("Col: %5d\n", x);
//  for (y = y_from; y < y_till; y++) {
  for (int xy = 0; xy < xy_range; xy++) {
    int x = x_from + (xy % x_width);
    int y = y_from + (xy / x_width);
        ray = cam->get_ray_at(x, y);
        L = trace_ray(ray, 0, cam->inter);
    #pragma omp critical
    cam->set_pixel(x, y, L);
  }
//  }
}
```

I tried many configurations. But what finally confuses me the most is that the above version, with a combined, single for, was the least efficient of all (150 seconds vs 120s for separate x and y for. The 'critical' does not noticeably change the timing.

More: though I would expect the single for-loop to parallelize each separate iteration, it doesn't. Using this method, 25 loops are executed as groups of 8 - 8 - 8 - 1 (8 cores). In fact the separate y-loops (commented out in listing) seem to distribute the load more efficiently. Removing the 'for' in 'parallel for' does improve
slightly (148 vs 150s ;)

Also, I tried local vs global definitions (with the necessary private pragmas). I tried to declare L and ray inside the loops. All to no avail...

I'd appreciate suggestions or pointers...

Here are some more precise data:

```
Single loop             Yes                     No                      No                      Yes    
'Critical"              No                      No                      Yes                     Yes
                ----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------------
                User    CPU     Mean    User    CPU     Mean    User    CPU     Mean    User    CPU     Mean
Scene 5         37.9    158.9   3.66    26.5    185.5   7.00    27.0    187.7   6.95    38.7    161.8   4.18
Scene 6         18.8    110     5.85    17.7    112     6.32    18.1    113.8   5.29    19.4    112.2   5.78
Scene 7         149     658.8   4.42    114     679.9   5.96    114     653.8   5.73    149     659.8   4.43
Plane           112.0   497.3   4.44    105     520.5   4.95    103.8   525     5.06    113.5   504.8   4.45     
5-balls         126     760.2   6.03    162.3   697.5   4.36    170.3   725.3   4.23    127.3   766.5   6.02
```

'Mean' is CPU/User, which is the mean core occupation. Note that in several cases, mean is only 4.xx.

Solution, and results:

```
Single loop             Yes                     No
                ----------------------  ----------------------
                User    CPU     Mean    User    CPU     Mean
Scene 5         23.9    190.1   7.95    24.4    190.7   7.82
Scene 6         14.3    114.2   7.98    14.5    114.9   7.92
Scene 7         85.5    675.9   7.91    106.9   698.8   6.54
Plane           72.7    579.1   7.97    72.6    578.4   7.97
5-balls         104.8   823.3   7.86    103.9   825.1   7.94
```

This excellent result is obtained by adding schedule(dynamic, 1) to
the #pragma omp parallel for line like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
```

which see to a run-time load distribution for cores (as opposed to
compile time).

Just one more note, the ', 1' parameter is to limit the size of the
chunks. It can be left out, in which case openmp uses a default
value. Maybe adding 1 made the load distribution too fine-grained,
but I cannot find any performance difference either way in this case .
I guess the raytracing task is too slow and hides any administrative 
overhead.

Comment: Could you maybe add some code examples of what you mean by "150 seconds vs 120s for separate x and y for"...."In fact the separate y-loops (commented out in listing) seem to distribute the load more efficiently"....and "Removing the 'for' in 'parallel for' does improve slightly"?

Comment: The code is the same as above, uncommented the separate for's and comment the xy-for (and the x/y separator). Separate for-loops, all the rest equal, give 120 seconds exec time. Single goes to 150s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a Whitted sytle ray tracer that operates on the full ray tree (reflection and refraction) in OpenCL.  I have not done it with OpenMP yet but that's my next goal.  If you want to learn OpenMP I would start with some simpler tasks first.  But let me make a few comments.

How are you doing your timing?  You wrote "Removing the 'for' in 'parallel for' does improve slightly".  That makes no sense.  Removing the for is going to run the same code on each thread not distribute the treads to different iterations (do some hello world tests to show this).  It should be slower not faster.  That makes me wonder how you do the timing.  I added some code to show how to do the timing.

You should not have to use `critical`.  If each iteration writes to a different pixel then it should not be necessary.  Depending on the complexity of your scene `critical` would likely make it much slower.

Lastly, to get the best performance you're going to want to use SSE/AVX as well and operate on multiple pixels at once.  This can be done though what's called packet based ray tracing.  See the following link for a good discussion on this http://graphics.stanford.edu/~boulos/papers/cook_gi07.pdf

Edit: Since each pixel can take different times you want to use schedule(dynamic) rather than schedule(static) which is normally (but not necessarily) the default.  See the code.

Ingo Wald's PhD thesis:
http://www.sci.utah.edu/~wald/PhD/

```
double dtime = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
{
    Ray ray;
    Color L;
    #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic)
    for (int xy = 0; xy < xy_range; xy++) {
        int x = x_from + (xy % x_width);
        int y = y_from + (xy / x_width);
        ray = cam->get_ray_at(x, y);
        L = trace_ray(ray, 0, cam->inter);
        cam->set_pixel(x, y, L);
     }
}
dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
printf("time %f\n", dtime);
```

Comment: Hi raxman... Thanks for the answer. As the times I am measuring are relatively large, in the order of tens or hundreds of seconds, I consider program setup negligible, and simply time the program execution time with 'time' (outside the program itself). I thought that would avoid any problems with openMP itself. I added the critical statement because I had some problems with random erroneous pixels. I also tried removing the 'critical', and timing was basically the same - logical because the array assignment time is again very short.

Comment: If you're getting erroneous pixels and need critical that indicates to me that you may have a race condition which cause performance hits.  Is it possible for "set_pixel(x, y, L)" to wrtie to the same pixel for different values of x, y?  What is L exactly?

Comment: The problem was that set_pixel wrote the pixel to the wrong location. The value was right, and it was missing from the other (correct) location. Strangely this does not seem to happen anymore (will test that).  One of the stranger things I notice is that usage falls from 8 cores to 3 long before the end of the render. The scene is basically constant complexity - no real bottlenecks. So this should not happen.

Comment: Since pixels can take much longer than others in ray tracing then three pixels could keep running after the other threads have finished.  The only way to fix that is with better load balancing.  One pedantic point.  I doubt you have 8 cores.  I think you have 4 cores and 8 "hardware" threads (due to hyper threading).  The distinction can be important.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.  You mean only three threads are running even though there are many pixels still to be rendered?  How do you know this?

Comment: Correct. I have the CPU activity graph which indicate 37% activity - which corresponds to 3 of 8 cores. It starts at 100%, then steps down, core by core to 37%, finally it stays at 25% for a couple of secs and finalizes.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the previous answer. The scene is the 'Stanford dragon' which is essentially about 50000 triangles - most of the same size. There are no pixels that could take that long - even though recursion depth is set to 5 max.

Comment: I added more measurements to the original message. 'Scene5' is pure spheres, 'Scene6' is mix spheres/triangles, 'Scene7' is only triangles. 'Plane' is a single plane and 2 spheres. 5-balls is one plane and 7 spheres. The last one seems very atypical, will do the tests again. The rest, not that CPU utilization is better of double loops.

Comment: About time measurements, I compared your example with the 'time' method I used and get 129.8s for the first, and 129.9s for the 'time' method. Little difference...

Comment: And a last comment before turning in (2:30 AM!): Could it be that OpenMP schedules (subdivides the loops) at the start of the run and does not adapt later on if some of the threads are slower than others? I tried to put in a printf with the 'y' loop variable and noticed that chunks of y values seem to be assigned to each core at the beginning. What happens if a core processed its workload earlier than others? This would really explain most of the problems I noticed, eg. if one core gets part of the 'easy' background.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this in the beginning.  With ray tracing you should be using schedule(dynamic).

Comment: Yes! Thanks for that, @raxman! Though admittedly, I _was_ near the solution yesterday, wasn't I? For some reason, Scene 7, dual loops version, suffers much more than the rest... Ah well...

Comment: yes, I did not see that you added something about dynamic.  I'm not sure you want to set the chunk size to 1.  I would try the default.  But of course it's worth trying different values.

Comment: Just did a quick check on one scene, set the chunksize to default (by not specifying it), and the times were the same. At 98% core occupation, I don't see much room for improvement anyway.

Comment: Good work!  Now read Ingo Wald's PhD thesis and try all his tricks (I added a link to the edit).  Also, I have been wanting to look into space filling curves for load balancing.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve#Other_implementations

Comment: The biggest performance gain I think you can get now from the hardware is by adapting your algorithm to use SSE/AVX.  Many people do it wrong and pack 3D vectors in one SSE register.  You should do it the way Ingo Wald did it.  Use a struct of arrays (instead of an array of struct) and operated on 4 rays at once (8 with AVX).

Comment: Ok, @raxman - I've been looking a bit into the sse/avx things and it seems quite interesting... And thanks for the link to Ingo's work - I even found a typo in his text and alerted him to it ;) I think I can get better gains by implementing better algorithms for optimizing the actual rendering - at least for now... And I don't want to loose my original goal of actually creating something nice with a renderer.

Comment: Well good luck!  I hope to get back to rendering in a few months.